# ¿Cómo saber cuando es el final de un salto físico? (Unity + C#)

Tags: c#, unity, rigidbody

Estoy tratando de saber cual es la condición correcta que se tiene que dar al final de un salto pero todo lo que he intentado está fallando. El salto lo he cálculdo usando las típicas ecuaciones de física de Dinámica de la partícula, Sólido rigido. Es decir (Energía cinética, Energía potencial, Fuerza).

```
float JumpVelocity = 0f;
private void Jump(float height, Vector2 direction)
{
    //cálculo de la velocidad
    JumpVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(2 * (rigidBody.gravityScale * Mathf.Abs(Physics.gravity.y)) * height);
  
    //cálculo de la fuerza
    float F = (rigidBody.mass * obstacleDistance) / Mathf.Pow(obstacleDistance / JumpVelocity, 2);

    if (direction == Vector2.left)
        F = -F;

    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, JumpVelocity);
    rigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(F, 0));

    isJumping = true;
}
```

El problema es que no encuentro la manera de saber cuando ha terminado el salto. He probado de diferentes formas.

Por ejemplo, tengo un Raycast checkeando el suelo constantemente y me setea una variable llamada "isGrounded" si estoy tocando el suelo es verdadera. Si intento lo siguiente no sirve porque "isJumping" es falso desde el mismo momento en el que se salta.

```
private void ResetIsJumping()
{
    if (isGrounded)
    {
        isJumping = false;
    }
}
```

También he probado de la siguiente forma pero también falla porque hay dos momentos durante el salto en que la velocidad podría ser cero (en el punto mas bajo y el mas alto del salto), aún asi nunca detecta el momento justo en que la velocidad es cero. Ni siquiera cuando está parado en el suelo la velocidad es exactamente cero. Además me pone la variable a falso desde el mismo instante en que empieza a caer y yo necesito que sea falso en el mismo instante en que toque el suelo después de la caída.

```
private void ResetIsJumping()
{
    if (rigidBody.velocity.y <= 0f)
    {
        isJumping = false;
    }
}
```

También he intentado hacerlo así, suponiendo que la velocidad final en caída al momento de tocar el suelo tiene que ser igual a la velocidad inicial pero con signo negativo. Pero tampoco funcina.

```
private void ResetIsJumping()
{
    if (rigidBody.velocity.y <= -JumpVelocity)
    {
        isJumping = false;
    }
}
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionar este problema?
Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encotré esto que parece ser que funciona. Por el momento no le he encontrado ningún fallo.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name=="Tilemap")
    {
        //Digo que no está saltando
        isJumping = false;
        //Le quito la fuerza de salto remanente que tuviera
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.velocity.x, 0);
    }
    
}
```

Aquí lo dejo por si a alguien mas le sirve de ayuda. Si alguien sabe una manera mejor de hacerlo que lo postee aquí por favor y le daré la respuesta por valida. Muchas Gracias!!